# Using binary system for Henry Classfication System.

Tags: binary, applications

In my forensic science class, we learned about the Henry classification system of fingerprints to categorize fingerprints based on the type of print each finger had. The system itself uses the decimal system, but I think it should use binary instead.

The classification method is described [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Classification_System), each finger is labeled from 1 to 10, starting with the right thumb and ending with the left pinky. If a finger has a print classified as a "whorl", then the finger would be given a designated value (16, 8, 4, 2, or 1) and otherwise 0. The numbers are added in a specific group and placed either in the numerator or denominator of a fraction, with 1 added to both the numerator and denominator. Any set of prints will have a range between 1/1 and 32/32.

To me, I see the use of binary as much more visually intuitive. Instead of a number like 17/5, 10000/00100 can be much easier to identify: the finger in the first position in the numerator has a whorl, and the finger in the third position in the bottom has a whorl. It all seems much simpler and better to use binary in this case, since the only question is whether or not a finger has a whorl print.

I feel that I may have overlooked a flaw of using binary, and that the original system had an advantage. Does anyone else feel the same as I do?